# Delete a Mongodb Database using Mongo Tools

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-tools

Using mongo tools only.....

Is there a way to delete a remote Mongo Atlas Database using the mongoDB Command Line DB tools, is it doable using MongoDB Atlas API (via curl), or is it only doable using the Mongo Shell ?? The system I am working on already has the command line tools, and I'm trying not add new software on to the machine.

Need this for CI/CD testing purposes.

Comment: Dropping a database via APi was discussed here: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/how-to-drop-a-database-with-mongodb-atlas-api/116764

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `db.runCommand( { dropDatabase: 1 } )` and its wrapper `db.dropDatabase()` from the command line `mongo` shell to drop a database and its associated files. Note that the database delete operation removes all the collections in it.

For example, from the `mongo` shell delete the "mydb" database:

```
use mydb
db.dropDatabase()

// -or- from any current database:

db.getSiblingDB("mydb").dropDatabase()
```

The following are the aspects which are concerned with this command: write concern, locks, user management, indexes and the clusters (replica sets and sharded); refer the following links for details: [dropDatabase command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/dropDatabase/) and [db.dropDatabase()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.dropDatabase/).

You can also [drop a database](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/databases/#drop-a-database) from the MongoDB Compass GUI tool.

You can also execute the drop database command from any of the MongoDB programming language driver APIs.